# Sharepoint import users from OpenLDAP (Ubuntu)

Tags: import, directory

We are running a Sharepoint 2013 server. How can we import users that are using Ubuntu as Client and OpenLDAP as Active Directory?

We want to connect those users from OpenLDAP to Sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a complicated scenario and require a fair amount of work. It involves two pieces, authentication and then (presumably) User Profile import.

For authentication, you'll need to set up Forms-based Authentication. Here is [an example with AD LDS](http://thesharepointfarm.com/sharepoint-and-active-directory-lightweight-directory-services/). You'll need to adapt it for use with OpenLDAP.

For User Profiles, you'll either need to create a manual sync job (that is, using the [Server OM](http://sharepointadlds.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Nauplius.ADLDS.FBA/FBA/UserProfiles.cs)), or use something like Microsoft Identity Manager and configure SharePoint to use the [External Identity Manager](http://thesharepointfarm.com/2013/06/using-an-external-identity-manager-for-sharepoint-user-profile-synchronization/) option in the UPA.

Given how complicated and difficult this configuration can be, it may be best to do a bit of research and then ask more specific questions where you run into issues.